# React - Coding Error

Tags: reactjs

I am following tutorial from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzqR10jG1pg
Using Code Editor: https://stackblitz.com

Coding error reads:

> Error in index.js (36:10)
>   '}' expected.

Error line reads:

```
render: function () {
```

How do I get this code to work?

Here is my Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));



    <div id="example"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

        var Bacon = React.createClass({

            render: function () {
                return (<h3>This is a simple component!</h3>);
            }

        });

        ReactDOM.render(<Bacon />, document.getElementById('example'));

    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are putting HTML code into your javascript (`index.js`) file. You should have a separate HTML file for that.

I can see you are trying to render two different apps.

First, when you use `ReactDOM.render(<Bacon />, document.getElementById('example'));` you're telling React to render the component Bacon in the HTML element that has an ID attribute 'example'.

Then, with `render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`, React will look for an element that has an ID attribute 'root'.

So you should have both elements in your HTML file, like the snippet below.

```js
// index.js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.name}</div>
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  var Bacon = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return (<h3>This is a simple component!</h3>);
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(<Bacon />, document.getElementById('example'));
</script>
```

Comment: Using Code Editor: https://stackblitz.com. I do not see "This is a simple component!" on the browser render. I am wondering - do you think I need a --- script src= "http for babel" --- to get this to work?